# How to plot and animate coordinates (latitude/longitude) data in R?

Tags: r, animation, plot, maps, coordinates

I have 10 lat and long points. With the code below, I can plot the coordinates, draw arrows in the order of their sequence and out-put a gif file that shows navigation order.

So far I was able to do this only with plot {graphics} function. because  arrow {graphics} and saveGIF{animation} only seems to work with the plot function. I am wondering if its possible to this a more appropriate library such as ggmap (edit: I had mistakenly said ggplot), googleVis and etc.

```
library(graphics)
library(animation)

lat <- c(34.083398,34.072467,34.030237,34.597334,34.587142,34.488386,33.443484,33.946902,33.062739,32.273711,32.272611)

lon <- c(-107.907107,-106.893156,-107.971542,-105.225107,-105.13397,-103.196355,-104.52479,-103.655698,-106.0156,-107.71744,-107.713977)

coords = data.frame(lat,lon)

x <- coords$lat ; y <- coords$lon 
s <- seq(length(x)-1)  # one shorter than data


saveGIF({
  for(s in 1:length(x)){
    plot(x,y)  
    arrows(x[s], y[s], x[s+1], y[s+1], col = 1:s)
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just remember to wrap your `ggplot` calls in `print` so they produce output. Toy example:

```
data=data.frame(i=1:100,x=runif(100),y=runif(100))
saveGIF({for(i in 2:100){print(ggplot(data[1:i,],aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point())}})
```

Just write your code to produce each frame with `ggplot2` functions and wrap in `print`. What did you try?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. This worked great; made me notice  that what I really need is ggmaps instead of ggplot for the lat/lon points with arrows.

Comment: Can you tick the little tick mark next to my answer to accept this and mark the question as 'answered'?

Comment: I think I will give-up my hopes in doing this in ggmap for now. So I tried, ggplot. It worked very well witn plotting the coords, but arrows function still doesn't seem to work on ggplot. Here is my code saveGIF({for(i in 2:30){print(ggplot(data.frame(x,y)[1:i,],aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point())
arrows(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1], col = 1:30)}})

Comment: No, ggplot doesn't work like that. Forget animation for a second and start a new question, describe what you want to plot, show the base graphics methods that do it (if you've done that), and add "I want to do this in ggplot (or with a ggmap background)"